# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class ViewPager

Tags: android, xml, view

here is my code, I try to slide screen in container activity, the full code is [here](https://github.com/roroco/vst/tree/cannot-slide-screen-on-main)

Container.groovy

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.container)
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager)
    pager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(fragmentManager))
}
```

container.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

error:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class ViewPager
           ...
            at ro.vst.Container.onCreate(Container.groovy:17)
```

Comment: Try changing this line `ViewPager pager = findViewById(R.id.pager)` to `ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager)`

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

I looked the code you posted on github and your [container.xml](https://github.com/roroco/vst/blob/cannot-slide-screen-on-main/app/src/main/res/layout/container.xml) has the following content:

```
<ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

The root should be `<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` and not `<ViewPager` since `ViewPager` exits only as part of the support library